# Getting an Embed Token for App Owns Data model in Power BI

Tags: php, powerbi, token, embed, powerbi-embedded

I've been working through how to implement getting a Power BI Embed token for the App Owns data model in Power BI. It's proving a little tricky
I've found a post: https://www.msbiblog.com/2018/01/12/power-bi-embedded-example-using-curl-and-php/
Which has helped but translating this into app owns data but I feel that I am missing a small but important point somewhere

Does anyone have ideas or code examples that will help put some light on this

thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's not very clear what are you missing, but here are the [official samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples) from Microsoft, including the demo how to implement [App owns data](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/App%20Owns%20Data) scenario. A good place to start is to read [Embed content in your application for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers) tutorial. You can see how things work in [the playground demo](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html).

To embed Power BI element in your application, you need to do the following:

- Register an application - go to [dev.powerbi.com/apps](https://dev.powerbi.com/apps) and register a native application. Select which permissions to grant it (if you aren't sure, for your first tests simply grant them all). Copy the guid - this is the app ID, a.k.a. client ID.
- Next step is to authenticate from your application and get an access token. Use Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for that - call some of the `acquireToken` methods of `AuthenticationContext` class. Here is one [ADAL client library](https://github.com/introp-software/azure-activedirectory-library-for-php) for PHP, and here is [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet) for these methods.
- Use this access token to call the Power BI REST API and get the `embedUrl` of the element you want to embed, e.g. [report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreportingroup#report).
- Use [Power BI JavaScript client](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding-Basics) to actually embed this element. You need to initialize one [embed configuration class](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details) and pass information about element type (report, dashboard, tile), where to find it (embedUrl), authentication (access token), some other configuration options (show or hide filters pane, navigation, etc.), filters to be applied and so on. In case you will use the access token acquired above, set `tokenType` to be `AAD`. This token has many privileges, so for security reasons you may want to use `Embed` token instead. In this case use the access token to call the REST API again (e.g. [Reports GenerateTokenInGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/reports_generatetokeningroup)).
- Call `powerbi.embed` method of the JavaScript client pass the embedded configuration to visualize this Power BI element in your app.

I will recommend you also to take a look at [Embedding basics](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding-Basics) article (and the rest of the articles in this wiki).